# How to get multiple Result Sets into variable or temp table while executing sp_execute_external_script command?

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure which encloses the following `sp_execute_external_script` command inside of a while-loop and I am getting as output every returned result set, separately. I am using SQL Server 2016 to do all this stuff.

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R',@script = N' some R code here ' ,@input_data_1 = N' SELECT * FROM #TempTable;'  
WITH 
    RESULT 
        SETS 
            (
                (
                    [filename] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                    [mobile_fraction] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                    [t_half] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                    [r_square] NVARCHAR(MAX) 
                )
            );
```

I would like to store all the returned data of the result sets into a @variable (or into a #temptable) in order for me to be able to continue the processing of these data. I have tried both the above cases (for instance `INSERT INTO @variable EXEC "myStoredProcedure"`)  but I am getting the following error

> Incorrect syntax near 'SETS'.

If I remove the `INSERT INTO @variable` line everything works fine. So, I was wondering if I could use such a "technique" with `execute sp_execute_external_script` command.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT..EXEC` will work if you remove the `WITH RESULTS SETS` as long as the output schema matches the table schema.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
  Test NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R',@script = N'OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(c("test"))' ,@input_data_1 = N''  

SELECT * FROM @TEMP
```